# Customized new account letter for GSuite?

Tags: google-workspace-for-business, g-suite-administrator

I added a new user to Google Suite. After the user is created a pop-up shows the user information (name, e-mail, password). Here it's possible to print a welcome letter that says something like:

> Hello {first name},
>
> You have a new Google Account with the {organization domain}
>   organization. Sign in to your Google Account to access the Google
>   services your organization provides. If your organization has G Suite,
>   Google services may include business-grade versions of Google Drive,
>   Gmail, and other Google services you can use to collaborate with your
>   team.
>
> ...

However this is very Google-specific letter, it's even signed by the Google Cloud Team, and the address at the bottom is Google's address at Mountain View, CA.

It would be a nice touch to customize this template to have our own company's information instead, but is it even possible to do so? And if it is, how can I do that?

Comment: Please search for the related help article  in https://support.google.com/a and describe your findings or if you didn't find anything add the keywords you used to search.

Comment: The only thing I found was the "Add users indivitually" article https://support.google.com/a/answer/33310?hl=en which mentions what I did ("Print login info for this user") simply as another optional action. No more details than that. I searched for "add users"